# Extract from reviews usernames that may or may not appear between a bold tag 

Tags: c#

I want to extract from reviews usernames that may or may not appear between a bold HTML tag, so how can I get the username ?

This is the HTML source code

```
<li class="uname2">Ajmeerajee</li>
<li class="uname"><b>naqvi.mn</b></li>
```

And I want to extract the usernames :

```
Ajmeerajee
naqvi.mn
```

So what would be the regular expression for this?

Comment: Stealing content is not something I want to help anyone with.

Comment: @Peter "Stealing content" is a strong allegation. There are many perfectly legitimate reasons for what the OP wants to do. Aren't we supposed to give everyone the benefit of doubt and do out best help them?

Comment: @Abbas I know its a strong allegation and there are some edge cases where this would be a legitimate question. Still, I wouldn't have said this if the poster would've at least used a proper account to pose the question. But this just doesn't look legit to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use Regular Expressions for parsing HTML, HTML is too complex for RE.

If your HTML markup is well formed, you can load it as XML and use xpath to find the text of `li` elements. Here's a code example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlString = @"<ul><li class=""uname2"">Ajmeerajee</li><li class=""uname"" ><b>naqvi.mn</b></li></ul>";
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//ul/li");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

Comment: i am trying to work on scrapper in c#  which will extract the reviews from a site but facing a problem where bold tags comes into picture otherwise it works

Answer (score 0):

If you load it as XML, you could parse it through that.